# changing state of widget is not reflected, using flutter

Tags: flutter, statefulwidget

password field has an "obscure" ability which is found in the buildInputForm defined below to hide and show the password string if clicked, the action is not reflected on the screen, i reverted back to older version of the code yet it did not change. im using VScode

```
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
      child: TextFormField(
        obscureText: isPassword,
        controller: controller,
        decoration: InputDecoration(
          hintText: hint,
          hintStyle: const TextStyle(color: kTextFieldColor),
          focusedBorder: const UnderlineInputBorder(
            borderSide: BorderSide(color: kPrimaryColor),
          ),
          suffixIcon: isPassword
              ? IconButton(
                  onPressed: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isObscure = !_isObscure;
                    });
                  },
                  icon: _isObscure
                      ? const Icon(
                          Icons.visibility_off,
                          color: kTextFieldColor,
                        )
                      : const Icon(
                          Icons.visibility,
                          color: kPrimaryColor,
                        ),
                )
              : null,
        ),
        validator: validator,
        onSaved: onSaved,
        keyboardType: keyboardType,
        inputFormatters: inputFormatters,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has logical bug.

Use this on buildInputForm

```
 obscureText: isPassword ? _isObscure : false,
```